# Lisp - Split Recursive

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I was trying to make a recursive function to split a list into two lists according the number of elements one wants.

> Ex:
>
> > (split  3 '(1 3 5 7 9))  ((1 3 5) (7 9))
> >
> > (split 7 '(1 3 5 7 9))  ((1 3 5 7 9) NIL)
> >
> > (split 0 '(1 3 5 7 9))  (NIL (1 3 5 7 9))

My code is like this:

```
(defun split (e L) 
  (cond ((eql e 0) '(() L))
        ((> e 0) (cons (car L) (car (split (- e 1) (cdr L))))))))
```

I don't find a way to join the first list elements and return the second list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tail recursive solution**

```
(defun split (n l &optional (acc-l '()))
  (cond ((null l) (list (reverse acc-l) ()))
        ((>= 0 n) (list (reverse acc-l) l))
        (t (split (1- n) (cdr l) (cons (car l) acc-l)))))
```

**Improved version**

(in this version, it is ensured that `acc-l` is at the beginning `'()`):

```
(defun split (n l)
  (labels ((inner-split (n l &optional (acc-l '()))
             (cond ((null l) (list (reverse acc-l) ()))
                   ((= 0 n)  (list (reverse acc-l) l))
                   (t (inner-split (1- n) (cdr l) (cons (car l) acc-l))))))
    (inner-split n l)))
```

Test it:

```
(split 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
;; returns: ((1 2 3) (4 5 6 7))
(split 0 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
;; returns: (NIL (1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
(split 7 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
;; returns ((1 2 3 4 5 6 7) NIL)
(split 9 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
;; returns ((1 2 3 4 5 6 7) NIL)
(split -3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
;; returns (NIL (1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
```

In the improved version, the recursive function is placed one level deeper (kind of *encapsulation*) by using `labels` (kind of `let` which allows definition of local functions but in a way that they are allowed to call themselves - so it allows recursive local functions).

**How I came to the solution:**

Somehow it is clear, that the first list in the result must result from consing one element after another from the beginning of `l` in successive order. However, consing adds an element to an existing list at its beginning and not its end.
So, successively consing the car of the list will lead to a reversed order.
Thus, it is clear that in the last step, when the first list is returned, it hast to be `reverse`d. The second list is simply `(cdr l)` of the last step so can be added to the result in the last step, when the result is returned.

So I thought, it is good to accumulate the first list into (`acc-l`) - the accumulator is mostly the last element in the argument list of tail-recursive functions, the components of the first list. I called it `acc-l` - accumulator-list.

When writing a recursive function, one begins the `cond` part with the trivial cases. If the inputs are a number and a list, the most trivial cases - and the last steps of the recursion, are the cases, when

1. the list is empty `(equal l '())` ---> `(null l)`
2. and the number is zero  ----> `(= n 0)` - actually `(zerop n)`. But later I changed it to `(>= n 0)` to catch also the cases that a negative number is given as input.

(Thus very often recursive `cond` parts have `null` or `zerop` in their conditions.)

When the list `l` is empty, then the two lists have to be returned - while the second list is an empty list and the first list is - unintuitively - the `reverse`d `acc-l`.
You have to build them with `(list )` since the `list` arguments get evaluated shortly before return (in contrast to `quote` = `'(...)` where the result cannot be evaluated to sth in the last step.)

When n is zero (and later: when n is negative) then nothing is to do than to return l as the second list and what have been accumulated for the first list until now - but in reverse order.

In all other cases `(t ...)`, the car of the list `l` is `cons`ed to the list which was accumulated until now (for the first list): `(cons (car l) acc-l)` and this I give as the accumulator list (`acc-l`) to `split` and the rest of the list as the new list in this call `(cdr l)` and `(1- n)`. This decrementation in the recursive call is very typical for recursive function definitions.

By that, we have covered all possibilities for one step in the recursion.
And that makes recursion so powerful: conquer all possibilities in ONE step - and then you have defined how to handle nearly infinitely many cases.

**Non-tail-recursive solution**
(inspired by Dan Robertson's solution - Thank you Dan! Especially his solution with `destructuring-bind` I liked.)

```
(defun split (n l)
  (cond ((null l) (list '() '()))
        ((>= 0 n) (list '() l))
        (t (destructuring-bind (left right) (split (1- n) (cdr l))
                    (list (cons (car l) left) right)))))
```

**And a solution with only very elementary functions** (only `null`, `list`, `>=`, `let`, `t`, `cons`, `car`, `cdr`, `cadr`)

```
(defun split (n l)
  (cond ((null l) (list '() '()))
        ((>= 0 n) (list '() l))
        (t (let ((res (split (1- n) (cdr l))))
              (let ((left-list (car res))
                    (right-list (cadr res)))
                (list (cons (car l) left-list) right-list))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember: split returns a list of two lists.

```
(defun split (e L) 
  (cond ((eql e 0)
         '(() L))       ; you want to call the function LIST
                        ;  so that the value of L is in the list,
                        ;  and not the symbol L itself

        ((> e 0)

         ; now you want to return a list of two lists.
         ; thus it probably is a good idea to call the function LIST

         ; the first sublist is made of the first element of L
         ;  and the first sublist of the result of SPLIT

         ; the second sublist is made of the second sublist
         ;  of the result of SPLIT

         (cons (car L)
               (car (split (- e 1)
                           (cdr L)))))))
```

Comment: `(split 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))` in CLISP returns `(1 . 2)` with this. Sth in the second part is not correct I think ...

Answer (score 2):

Well let’s try to derive the recursion we should be doing.

```
(split 0 l) = (list () l)
```

So that’s our base case. Now we know

```
(split 1 (cons a b)) = (list (list a) b)
```

But we think a bit and we’re building up the first argument on the left and the way to build up lists that way is with `CONS` so we write down

```
(split 1 (cons a b)) = (list (cons a ()) b)
```

And then we think a bit and we think about what `(split 0 l)` is and we can write down for `n>=1`:

```
(split n+1 (cons a b)) = (list (cons a l1) l2) where (split n b) = (list l1 l2)
```

So let’s write that down in Lisp:

```
(defun split (n list)
  (ecase (signum n)
    (0 (list nil list))
    (1 (if (cdr list)
           (destructuring-bind (left right) (split (1- n) (cdr list))
             (list (cons (car list) left) right))
           (list nil nil)))))
```

The most idiomatic solution would be something like:

```
(defun split (n list)
  (etypecase n
    ((eql 0) (list nil list))
    (unsigned-integer
      (loop repeat n for (x . r) on list
        collect x into left
        finally (return (list left r))))))
```

Comment: Ah `destructuring-bind` - this is quite elegantly solved! And the `(if (cdr list)` part is also neat. Ah but I also see: `(ecase (signum n) (0 first-case-handling) (1 second-case-handling))` can be simplified to `(if (nullp n) first-case-handling second-case-handling)`. Or `(cond ((nullp n) first-case-handling)) (t second-case-handling))` which is better readable, isn't it?

Comment: Instead of the `etypecase`, why not `(if (zerop n) …)`?  I'd rather check types separately, using `check-type` or `assert`.

Comment: It was lazy. I typed it on my phone and `etypecase` lets me combine validation, and special cases.

Comment: The finally clause is evaluated for side effects.  If you want to return something there, you need to use `return` or `return-from`.

Comment: @Svante yes you’re right. I suspect there might be an off-by-one error there too.